# Toggle script when other div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright. So I'm using this simple script which toggles divs. You all know how it works, I'm sure.

```
<div class="side-menu"> <!-- on click na sliku -> otvara div -> fadein -->
    <div id="showabout">
    <img src="img/info.png" class="hvr-grow" style="cursor: pointer;"> 
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="showservices">
    <img src="img/list.png" class="hvr-grow" style="cursor: pointer;" >
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="showportfolio">
    <img src="img/briefcase.png" class="hvr-grow" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="showcontact">
    <img src="img/phone-call.png" class="hvr-grow" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div id="about" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                <p> About Us </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="services" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                <p> Services </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                <p> Portfolio </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                <p> Contact </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#showabout').click(function() {
                    $('#about').fadeToggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#showservices').click(function() {
                    $('#services').slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#showportfolio').click(function() {
                    $('#portfolio').fadeToggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#showcontact').click(function() {
                    $('#contact').slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

So now I've got two questions. The first one is: When you toggle the #about div, it appears, as it should. But then when you click on #showservices it should remove the about div and replace it with the services one, they shouldn't go one across the other.

And the second question is; how can I turn all these into one script? It seems stupid to have 4 's when I'm sure they all can fit in one cleaner script.

Comment: Could you post your `HTML`?

Comment: Is there a reason why some divs have a `slideToggle` effect while others use `fadeToggle`?

Comment: On click #showabout other three should be hidden and as for others too, this is what you are asking for ?

Comment: @Gpx Different effects, wanted it to be like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify things by storing some context in data attributes.  I also took a little CSS from the in-line to make it a little easier to read.  I think this is the effect you are looking to achieve (a cross fade between result panes), but if not let me know and I'll see what I can do to help.

```js
$(function(){

  $(".side-menu .slide-menu-item").on("click", function(){
    var $target = $("#" + $(this).attr("data-target"));
    $target.siblings().fadeOut();
    $target.fadeIn();
  });

});
```

```css
.slide-menu-item { cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 1em; }
.main { position: relative; }
.main .panel { position: absolute; display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side-menu"> <!-- on click na sliku -> otvara div -> fadein -->
  <div id="showabout" class="slide-menu-item" data-target="about">
    <img src="img/info.png" class="hvr-grow">
  </div>
  <div id="showservices" class="slide-menu-item" data-target="services">
    <img src="img/list.png" class="hvr-grow">
  </div>
  <div id="showportfolio" class="slide-menu-item" data-target="portfolio">
    <img src="img/briefcase.png" class="hvr-grow">
  </div>
  <div id="showcontact" class="slide-menu-item" data-target="contact">
    <img src="img/phone-call.png" class="hvr-grow">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div id="about" class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                <p> About Us </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="services" class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                <p> Services </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio" class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                <p> Portfolio </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                <p> Contact </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showabout').click(function() {
            $('#about').fadeToggle("slow");
    });
    $('#showservices').click(function() {
            $('#about').hide();
            $('#services').slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $('#showportfolio').click(function() {
            $('#portfolio').fadeToggle("slow");
    });
    $('#showcontact').click(function() {
            $('#contact').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That works just when going from #about to #services.

Answer (score 0):

Give to all your pages `DIV`s a class like `class="page"`
and to all your buttons a class like `class="btn"`

Than this should do the job:

```
<script>
  jQuery(function( $ ) { // DOM ready

    var $pages = $(".page"); // Get all pages!

    $('.btn').click(function() {
      // Every .btn has an ID "showsomething". let's get the suffix after "show"***
      var pageId = this.id.split("show")[1];
      var $page = $("#"+  pageId);
      $pages.not($page).slideUp();
      $page.slideToggle();
    });

  });
</script>
```

To combine fade or slide, in the logic above than you can also do something like:

```
if(pageId==="someDesiredId") {
   // do this animation
} else {
   // do else kind of animation
}
```